# adding a static UITableView to a regular custom view

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, ios5, storyboard

I have a custom view controller that has a view on the bottom half.

I would like to add a static UITableView on the top half.

So I dragged a UITableView on the view controller but apparently that is not allowed since static table views only are only embeddable in UIViewControllers.

I went to my code and made my controller extend UITableView but that doesn't fix the issue.

How do I add my static UITableView as a second view in my custom controller?

EDIT: Perhaps having a table view not taking up the whole screen is not very well supported in iOS storyboards. Maybe I will just use regular tables on a view since i just need 3 static rows.

Comment: how about `[yoursecondview addsubview:tableview];`

Comment: my table view should reside inside my secondview but on the top of the screen. With the table view taking the top 50 % of the screen, and my second view, taking the space of the bottom half

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by making my second view controller a simple UIViewController that implements the delegate and datasource, dragging a dynamic table on it and setting the rows and sections "statically" in code. Now I have my two views correctly cohabiting in a large view.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something simple like this:

```
UITableViewController *tbv = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithFrame:[CGRect whateverSize/Location]];
[self.view addSubview:tbv];
```

Be sure when doing this to also write needed delegate functions such as `numberOfRowsInSection:` , `numberOfSections:` , `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

Be sure to check out the [UITableView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/)

Comment: I thought the whole point of static table views was to not implement the delegate and data source, and hence write the delegate functions.

Comment: You still have to, they don't know what the values are without specifying them. How does the table view know how many rows there are?

Comment: The table has the sections, rows and content you give it in the storyboard.